# Alternative to Redis' SCAN for auto-suggestions feature in a search bar?

Tags: redis

I have a simple redis DB where the key value is like so:

`symptom_name: symptom_id`

In my search bar, I'd like to implement an auto suggestions feature that will display any symptoms that are similar.

For example, typing 'pain' may also bring up 'stomach pain', 'knee pain', etc.

I thought about using the `SCAN` command matching with patterns to quickly fetch all the symptom names that are similar, but the problem is that the scan command can't fetch all the keys that match the pattern in one go.

What's my alternative here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is autocomplete with Redis explained by the author of Redis:
[Auto Complete with Redis](http://oldblog.antirez.com/post/autocomplete-with-redis.html)